# Python `ModuleNotFoundError` two dirs with same name

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, python-importlib

My python `sys.path` looks like this (only the first 2 paths are of interest):

```py
(Pdb) pp sys.path
['/home/michael/project/src/dist',
 '/home/michael/project/src/core',
 '/home/michael/project/src',
 '/usr/lib/python39.zip',
 '/usr/lib/python3.9',
 '/usr/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload',
 '/home/michael/.venv/project/lib/python3.9/site-packages',
 '/home/michael/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']
```

The first two dirs:
`/home/michael/project/src/dist` and `/home/michael/project/src/core` both contain a package called `app`, and within it are other packages.

Lets say we have two packages `foo` and `bar`:

- `/home/michael/project/src/core/app/foo/__init__.py`
- `/home/michael/project/src/dist/app/bar/__init__.py`

It seems python stops looking through the first dir it finds, instead of searching them all, e.g.:

```py
import importlib

pack = importlib.import_module('app.bar') 
print(pack) # <module 'app.bar' from '/home/michael/project/src/dist/app/bar/__init__.py'>

pack = importlib.import_module('app.foo') 
# *** ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app.foo'
```

**IMPORTANT** - I can't override how django searchs and loads various apps, thats part of the Django framework, so importing via filename is not an option for me.

Is there an easy fix to make python find my modules, or am I using a poor design pattern?

The reason I have two modules with the same name, is I am creating a Django framework that has `core` apps, and for certain configuations it has `dist` (distribution) apps. Maybe a distribution app needs to be used again somewhere else, then one can simply move it from `dist` into `core`, and everything continues to work. One does not have to be aware whether the app is part of the `core` apps or `dist` apps.

Answer (score 0):

The solutions seems to be [native-namespace-packages](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/packaging-namespace-packages/#native-namespace-packages)

Just omit the `__init__.py` from both `app` dirs.